# How to update the record from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Table1

```
ID     Loc
-----------
001    null
002    null
003    PYD
004    null
....
```

Table2

```
ID     Loc
-----------
001    TMB
002    null
003    PYD
004    SHD
....
```

I want to update table1 from table2. I'd need something like this:

```
update table1 set LoC = Select LoC from table2
```

And the expected output:

Table1

```
ID     Loc
-----------
001    TMB
002    null
003    PYD
004    SHD
....
```

How do I update table1 from table2?

Comment: Why was the sql-server-2000 tag removed? Is this question not for sql-server-2000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like:

```
update t
 set t.loc = t2.loc
 from table1 t
 inner join table2 t2 on t.id =t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update table1 set LoC = (Select LoC from table2 where table2 .ID =  table1 .ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you need?

```
update table1
set Loc = t2.Loc
from table1 t1 join table2 t2
   on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update table1
set Loc = table2.Loc
from table2
where table1.ID = table2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins.

```
update t1 set t1.Loc=t2.Loc
From Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2
on t1.Id=t2.Id
```

Comment: Join needs on, not where clause.